# Not able to start elasticsearch 2.X

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have installed elastic search 2.3 using yum install method and I bounded my system IP in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml (network.host=IP)`, while starting the elastic search getting the below error:

> Stopping elasticsearch:                                    [  OK  ]
>   Starting elasticsearch: Exception in thread "main" BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /192.168.37.164:9400]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
>   Likely root cause: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested addressat sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
>   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
>   at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)

How to resolve this?

Comment: Either the IP you've specified is not the correct IP address of the machine or port 9300 is already taken by another process.

Comment: Wein , Since it is a virtual machine I have assigned private IP instead of public IP and the problem is resolved.Thanks